# Test Class Coverage Issues with Inner Class - Need assistance to increase code coverage

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, failing-tests

I am currently having an issue with test coverage for an inner class and need assistance. I am not sure how to get past the validation method that is being executed within the save method. The validation method is used to validate the data before being able to save. I am not sure how to add the list of Opportunity Contact Roles and set up the test data in a way to make sure the validation passes.

I have a visualforce page where the opportunity contact roles get added to a list before save. When the opportunity saves the opportunity contact roles will get created. Users can add and remove opportunity contact roles before the record gets saved.

Any assistance on setting up a test class to handle this would be greatly appreciated. Below is my controller and section of my visualforce page.

**Apex Controller:**

```
public with sharing class newOpportunity_AC 
{

    public Integer RowToRemoveCR { get; set; }
    public list<OpportunityContactRole> todeletelinesCR = new list<OpportunityContactRole>();  
    public list<OCRItem> SelectedOpportunityContact;

    public OCRItem[] getSelectedOCRItems ()
    {   
       for(integer i = 0; i<SelectedOpportunityContact.size();i++)
       {
           SelectedOpportunityContact[i].RowNumCR = i;
       }
       return SelectedOpportunityContact;
    }

    public void setSelectedOCRItems(list<OCRItem> SelectedOpportunityContact)
    {
     this.SelectedOpportunityContact = SelectedOpportunityContact;
    }

    public newOpportunity_AC(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 
    {

        contactId = system.currentpagereference().getparameters().get('retURL');
        this.oppor = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
        oppOwner = userinfo.getFirstName()+' '+userinfo.getLastName();

        SelectedOpportunityContact = new List<OCRItem>();

        if(this.oppor.Id == null)
        {
            SelectedOpportunityContact.add(new OCRItem(new OpportunityContactRole ()));
        }
        else
        {
            for(OpportunityContactRole OCR : [Select id, ContactId, OpportunityId, IsPrimary, Role from OpportunityContactRole
                                        where OpportunityId = :this.oppor.Id])
            {
                system.debug(OCR);
                SelectedOpportunityContact.add(new OCRItem(OCR));
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddlineCR()
    {

            if(!validateErrorsAddContactRole())
            {
                SelectedOpportunityContact.add(new OCRItem(new OpportunityContactRole ()));  
            }

    }

    public void removelineCR()
    {
            if(SelectedOpportunityContact[RowToRemoveCR].OCR.id != null){
                todeletelinesCR.add(SelectedOpportunityContact[RowToRemoveCR].OCR);
            }

            SelectedOpportunityContact.remove(RowToRemoveCR);
    }


    public class OCRItem 
    {
        public OpportunityContactRole OCR {get; set;}
        public Integer RowNumCR {get; set;}

        public OCRItem(OpportunityContactRole o)
        {
            system.debug(o);
            OCR = o;
        }

    }

    public pagereference saveOpp()
    {
        if(!validateErrors())
        {


            this.oppor.StageName = stageValue;
            this.oppor.CloseDate = system.today();
            this.oppor.in_Progress_Stage__c = this.oppor.StageName;
            insert this.oppor;


            list<OpportunityContactRole> contactRolesToBeAdded = new list<OpportunityContactRole>();
            for(integer i = 0; i<SelectedOpportunityContact.size(); i++)
            {
                if(SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR.OpportunityId == null)
                {
                    SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR.OpportunityId = this.oppor.Id;
                }
                contactRolesToBeAdded.add(SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR);

            }

            system.debug(contactRolesToBeAdded);

            if(!contactRolesToBeAdded.isempty())
            {
                if(contactRolesToBeAdded.size() >= 1 && SelectedOpportunityContact[0].OCR.Role != '' && SelectedOpportunityContact[0].OCR.ContactID != null)
                {
                    upsert contactRolesToBeAdded;
                }

            }

            oppVal.updateTaskStatusOnceOppSaved(this.oppor);
            pagereference pf = new pagereference('/'+this.oppor.Id);
            pf.setredirect(true);
            return pf;
            //return null;
        }

    }

    public boolean validateErrors()
    {



        Integer primaryCount = 0;
        Boolean ocrRowZeroMissingData = false;
        Boolean ocrEmptyRow = false;
        Boolean ocrFieldMissingData = false;
        for(integer i = 0; i<SelectedOpportunityContact.size();i++)
        {
            if(SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR.IsPrimary == true)
            {
                primaryCount++;
            }

            if(SelectedOpportunityContact.size() == 1 && ((SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR.ContactId == null && SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR.Role != null) || (SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR.ContactId != null && SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR.Role ==  null)))
            {
                ocrRowZeroMissingData = true;
            }
            if(SelectedOpportunityContact.size() > 1 && (SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR.ContactId == null && SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR.Role == ''))
            {
                ocrEmptyRow = true;
            }
            if(SelectedOpportunityContact.size() > 1 && (SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR.ContactId == null || SelectedOpportunityContact[i].OCR.role == null))
            {
                ocrFieldMissingData = true;
            }

        }

        if(primaryCount > 1)
        {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Contact Role Section: Please ensure only one contact is listed as primary before saving.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            isRequiredFiledsMissing = true;
        }

        if(!SelectedOpportunityContact.isempty())
        {
            if(primaryCount == 0 && !SelectedOpportunityContact.isempty() && SelectedOpportunityContact[0].OCR.role != '' && SelectedOpportunityContact[0].OCR.contactId != null)
            {
                ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Contact Role Section: Please ensure a contact is listed as primary before saving.');
                ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
                isRequiredFiledsMissing = true;
            }
        }
        if(ocrRowZeroMissingData)
        {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Contact Role Section: Please ensure the Primary, Contact, and Role fields are not empty or leave all fields as blank.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            isRequiredFiledsMissing = true;
        }

        if(ocrEmptyRow)
        {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Contact Role Section: Please remove any additional empty rows.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            isRequiredFiledsMissing = true;
        }

        if(ocrFieldMissingData)
        {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Contact Role Section: Please ensure the Contact and Role fields are not empty.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            isRequiredFiledsMissing = true;
        }

        return isRequiredFiledsMissing;
    }
}
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:outputPanel id="CRPageBlockContainer">
<apex:outputPanel id="CRPageBlock">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Contact Roles" rendered="true" columns="1">
    <apex:outputText value="When creating a contact role, you must indicate only 1 contact as primary" style="font-family:georgia,garamond,serif;font-weight:bold;" />

    <apex:pageBlockTable value = "{!SelectedOCRItems}" id="contactRoleTable" var="cr"> 
        <apex:column headervalue="Action"  >
            <apex:commandlink value="Remove" action="{!removelineCR}" immediate="true" rerender="CRPageBlockContainer,pageMessageItem">
                <apex:param name="row" value="{!cr.RownumCR}" assignTo="{!RowToRemoveCR}"/>
            </apex:commandlink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Primary">
            <apex:inputField value="{!cr.OCR.isPrimary}" required="false"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Contact">
            <apex:inputField value="{!cr.OCR.ContactId}" required="false"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Role">
            <apex:inputField value="{!cr.OCR.Role}" required="false"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>

    <br/>
    <apex:commandbutton value="Add Additional Contact Role Lines" action="{!AddlineCR}"  rerender="CRPageBlockContainer,pageMessageItem" status="statusProcessing" /> <!-- immediate="true" -->
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: What do you have so far for a test class?

Comment: But, most important - why on earth someone else have to end up writing tests on someone else's code, and why behind that code there isn't a strong (pfff) documentation (ahaha) which supports future minds working on it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about your current test class, but you can instantiate a list of your inner class in your test class like so:

**Test Class.**

```
List<newOpportunity_AC.OCRItem> testList = new List<newOpportunity_AC.OCRItem>();
```

To test your method you would do:

```
newOpportunity_AC testCon = new newOpportunity_AC(new ApexPages.StandardController(testOpp));

List<newOpportunity_AC.OCRItem> testList = testCon.getSelectedOCRItems();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer to this is a **static variable**. 
This is an example that you can use to create contact roles for your test. 
Add this to your class:

```
public static List<Contact> AssociateContacts = null;
```

It needs to be on your outer class because it is not possible to insert static variables in your inner classes.
Add this statement in your inner class, preferably on your first lines.

```
if(AssociateContacts != null)
   CreateSomeContactRoles(newList, AssociateContacts);
```

Now we add the last part in your the apex class. The last part should be this method:

```
private static void CreateSomeContactRoles(
   List<Opportunity> ops, List<Contact> cts)
   {
      List<OpportunityContactRole> newocrs = 
           new List<OpportunityContactRole>(); 
   for(Integer x=0; x<ops.size(); x++)
   {
      newocrs.add(
          new OpportunityContactRole(
          OpportunityId = ops[x].id,
          ContactId = cts[x].id)); 

   }
   insert newocrs; 
}
```

Now we need to make the modifications to your test class. You should do something like this:

```
   static testMethod void testThis()
   {
     Opportunity op = new Opportunity(
       name='optest', StageName = 'Prospecting',
       CloseDate = Date.Today());

     Contact ct = new Contact(LastName='newct'); 
     insert ct; 
     newOpportunity_AC.AssociateComtacts = 
          new List<Contact>{ct};

     insert op; 
 }
```

You can use this pattern for those scenarios in which you need to test a class but you need to create mock records to bypass dependencies. There are many possibilities, you need to adjust your code for each situation. 
Hope it helps!